# Autoload de models no Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Eu tenho uma API em NodeJS onde criei um arquivo para ser meu datasource, neste arquivo eu faço o autoload das minhas models lendo os arquivos da minha app e para cada uma importo no sequelize. O código é este:

```js
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
let database = null;

// load all model files into models, to import in sequelize
const loadModels = (sequelize) => {
  const dir = path.join(__dirname, '../src/');
  const models = [];

  fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach((subDir) => {
    const subDirFiles = path.join(dir, subDir);


    fs.readdirSync(subDirFiles).forEach((file) => {
      if (file.indexOf('model.js') !== -1) {
        const modelFile = path.join(subDirFiles, file);
        const model = sequelize.import(modelFile);
        models[model.name] = model;
      }
    });
  });

  return models;
};

export default (app) => {
  if (!database) {
    const config = app.config;
    const op = Sequelize.Op;
    const sequelize = new Sequelize(
      ...
    );

    database = {
      sequelize,
      Sequelize,
      models: {},
    };

    database.models = loadModels(sequelize);

    sequelize.sync().done(() => database);
  }

  return database;
};
```

Minha dúvida é como fazer este mesmo autoload de models para o mongoose?

Eu já atualizei meu datasource mas não consigo fazer o autoload da model, a estrutura do meu arquivo Model recebe a conexão e o mongoose no construtor, desta maneira:

```js
export default (conn, mongoose) => {
  const Users = conn.model(collection.Users, new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    }));

  return Users;
};
```

Alguma ideia de como resolver isto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,
Eu criei um boilerplate para projetos em node com express + mongodb, utilizo o mongoos como ODM, os módulos faço o import deles usando o express-load e você pode dar uma olhada nele, acho que você pode tirar proveito dessa estrutura.

https://github.com/borgert-inc/express-api-startkit

Comment: Obrigado Odirlei, teu fonte me ajudou, boa solução. :)